# Android How to retry downloading automatically from where it left if internet connection goes away using FTP protocol

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ftp

**Below Is the code for downloading file using FTP in android. It is working fine but in case internet goes off during download, it doesn't retry.
I want it should automatically retry whenever internet comes back and should start downloading from there, where it left. Please help me.**

```
 public static void downloadFile(Context context) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            client.connect("test.rebex.net");
            client.login("demo", "password");
            String filename = "ftpp.png";
             String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + filename;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            client.retrieveFile("/pub/example/" + "KeyGenerator.png", fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FTPClient.setRestartOffset`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setRestartOffset(long)) to tell the server to start the download from place, where the transfer was interrupted before.